# Or'ing together should.js clauses

Tags: should.js

How do you create an or'd condition with should.js.  i.e. something like

```
cityName.should.startWith('A').or.companyName.should.startWith('B');
```

... But this is not valid syntax. Either clause works fine independently but I don't know how to combine them. What is a valid way to express this?

Comment: There is no .or in should.js, but you always can raise an issue on github about it.

Comment: That's why I am asking the question :)